# Trimming Form Field Data

Tags: javascript, php, forms, youtube, trim

I have an html form field on my webpage for users to submit YouTube 'share' video links.

However, I only want a portion of the link passed.

When using the YouTube 'copy and paste''share' option, their URL's all seem to start with:

https://youtu.be/

What I would like to do (If possible), is when my users enter the full URL...

For Example:
https://youtu.be/TP8RB7UZHKI

I would only like the: TP8RB7UZHKI to show up on the php results page.

I would like the https://youtu.be/ portion of the URL to always be omitted (Trimmed off of the beggining).

I could instruct my site visitors do it when filling out the form, but that might be confusing to most of them, and I can't afford the mistakes.

I have included a very stripped down version of the html form and the php results page codes below.

Again... I don't know if this is even possible, but if so, I would appreciate advice and/or an example on how to achieve this.

The Form Page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    body {margin-top:100px; margin-left:50px;}
    .videoURL{width:300px; height:25px;}
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form action="videoURLUploadResults.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    Video URL
    <input class="videoURL" ID="videoURL" name="videoURL" value="" autocomplete="off"/>

    <input class="submitButton" type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">
    </button>

    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The Video URL Upload Result PHP Page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>body{margin-top:100px; margin-left:50px;}</style>
    </head>

    <body>

    <?php $videoURL = ($_POST['videoURL']); echo  $videoURL;?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `str_ireplace()` in php to replace https://youtu.be/ with  empty string. Its syntax:

```
str_ireplace(find,replace,string,count)
```

Your php code will be:

```
 <?php $videoURL = ($_POST['videoURL']); echo  str_ireplace("https://youtu.be/","",$videoURL);?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your answer worked best for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

```
//on This page Use string replace function 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>body{margin-top:100px; margin-left:50px;}</style>
</head>

<body>

<?php $videoURL = ($_POST['videoURL']);    

 $videoURLFinal=str_replace('https://youtu.be/', '', $videoURL);

 echo $videoURLFinal;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the substr(string,start,length) function of php if "https://youtu.be/" is common in every link that user enters.

example:-

```
$link="https://youtu.be/TP8RB7UZHKI"; //your post data from your example i.e $_POST['videoURL']

$startlen=strlen("https://youtu.be/");// length of the string you want to remove

$totallen=strlen($link); //total length of the string

$videoURL=substr($link,$startlen,$totallen); // using substring to get the result

echo $videoURL;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.